# Memory leaks in default Cocos2d-x 3.5+ Projects?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've created a new project using Cocos2d-x 3.5. Without changing anything, I ran the Mac project and used the XCode Leak instrument to check it out, and found I was getting a single spike of memory leaks a short while into the program. I got the same behaviour on Windows using Visual Studios memory leak checks. However, I've run some sample projects (including ones built with 3.5) through this same process and they don't have any leaks.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Is there some setting I missed that would cause memory leaks in a default project setup?

Comment: Is build flag is same? The new project and sample project area built as DEBUG or RELEASE?